# What does the eta notation mean in the naming of a transition metal complex?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature, coordination-compounds

I am reading a paper ([Gutel et al., *J. Mater. Chem.* **2007**, *17*, 3290-3292](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/Content/ArticleLanding/2007/JM/b706139k)) and I have come across the following reaction:

> In organic solvents, the decomposition under mild conditions of
>   ($\eta^4$-1,5-cyclooctadiene)($\eta^6$-1,3,5-cyclooctatriene)ruthenium(0),
>   Ru(COD)(COT), under a dihydrogen atmosphere gives ruthenium
>   nanoparticles (RuNPs), by releasing cyclooctane (COA).
>
> $$\text{Ru(COD)(COT)} + \text{H}_2 \rightarrow \text{RuNPs} + \text{COA}$$

What do the $\eta^4$ and $\eta^6$ notations represent?  Do they somehow specify the coordination "connectivity" of the Ru(0) and the COD and COT coordinating ligands?

Below, I have drawn the (two-dimensional) structures of COD and COT.  How would I draw the connectivity of Ru(COD)(COT), or is it not specified in the given name?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> What do the $\eta^4$ and $\eta^6$ notations represent? Do they somehow specify the coordination "connectivity" of the Ru(0) and the COD and COT coordinating ligands?

**They do.**

The $\eta$-notation denotes the [hapticity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hapticity) of the ligand, which is the number of atoms in the ligand bonded to the metal center.

[image]

In your image, shown above, cyclooctadiene (COD), has two alkene functional groups. A transition metal can coordinate to just one alkene, which would be $\eta^2$, or to both alkenes, which would be $\eta^4$.

Cyclooctatriene (COT) has three alkenes. A metal center can be coordinated at one ($\eta^2$), two ($\eta^4$), or all three ($\eta^6$) alkenes.