# Coordination compounds with alkene ligands

Tags: nomenclature, coordination-compounds

I came across this compound: **$\ce{[Pd(η^2-C2H4)Cl2(H2O)]}$**

What does that '$\eta^2$' sign mean? I am guessing that it means that the ligand is bidentate because if it wasn't, I don't think it is possible (well it would be rare) for a metal to be only co-ordinates by 3 ligands.

If this is the case, how can the carbon atom in ethene bond to Pd as it doesn't have a lone pair? Does the double break and hence the 2 carbons bond to the metal?

Comment: I took the liberty of changing your title. See, it's not really about nomenclature, it's more about the nature of this compound.

Comment: ‘because if it wasn't, I don't think it is possible (well it would be rare) for a metal to be only co-ordinates by 3 ligands.’ There are two chlorines, water *and* ethylene. Assuming ethylene be bidentate, that would be five ligands; otherwise four. Perfectly normal for palladium. Also, complexes such as $\ce{[Ag(CN)2]-}$ (two ligands) exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ethylene is a monodentate ligand and there are 4 ligands total: ethylene,  two chlorides, and water.

Regarding hapticity, you can find a great answer here: [What does the eta notation mean in the naming of a transition metal complex?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4673/what-does-the-eta-notation-mean-in-the-naming-of-a-transition-metal-complex)

While a chapter can be dedicated to the nature of organometallic bonding, I think it is practical to say that it is the two electrons in the pi-bond that are involved in bonding to the metal center.

Answer (score 1):

It is not carbon that is donating a pair - instead, it is a $\pi$ bond as a whole. Its two electrons, which were shared between two carbons, are now shared between them *and* palladium in a kind of multicentered bond.

There is a huge class of compounds where organic molecules are attached to a metal in the same way. With larger conjugated $\pi$-systems, we may have ligands of $\eta^5$ coordination (look up [ferrocene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrocene)) and more, all the way to $\eta^8$ and maybe beyond that.

Comment: I would +1 this, but the OP obviously does not know about hapticity, so I feel you should include a note on what the notation actually *means*.

Comment: That's covered by the other answer already, so why bother.